# Cannot authenticate with AWS user pool on iOS Obj-C. Sign-up works

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Using the sample app works. Using the sample app's `SignInViewController` in my app does not work. I've duplicated much of the sample app into my `AppDelelgate`.

I've modified the `SignInViewController` since I'm navigating to it to log in.

When I use user getDetails, my delegate code (`startPasswordAuthentication`) works. But when I use signInPressed: nothing happens.

**Here is my AppDelegate:**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AWSConstants.h"
#import "PeepVC.h"
#import "WelcomeViewController.h"
//#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
@import GoogleMapsBase;
@import GooglePlaces;

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) AWSTaskCompletionSource<NSNumber *>* rememberDeviceCompletionSource;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
{
    GMSPlacesClient *_placesClient;
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
}
@synthesize cognitoId,locationManager,awsUser,awsPW;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];


    // new pool info for users
    //setup service config
    AWSServiceConfiguration *serviceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:nil];

    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration alloc] initWithClientId:@"--omitted--"
                                                                                                                  clientSecret:@"--omitted--"
                                                                                                                        poolId:@"--omitted--"];


    [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration:serviceConfiguration userPoolConfiguration:configuration forKey:@"UserPool"];
    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];
    pool.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"Pool:%@",pool);

    NSLog(@"AWS configuration:%@",configuration);
    NSLog(@"AWS service configuration:%@",serviceConfiguration);
    NSLog(@"AWS Cognito Identity Pool:%@",pool.userPoolConfiguration);

    NSString *deviceInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name:%@ Model:%@ (%@:%@)", [UIDevice currentDevice].name, [UIDevice currentDevice].model, [UIDevice currentDevice].systemName, [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion];

    NSLog(@"Device Info:%@",deviceInfo);

    [GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:@"--omitted--"];

    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setupMainView) name:@"registerForNotifications" object:nil];
    }

    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.venueDataModel = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    self.venueDataModelIndices = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    self.venueUserDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    //Set signedUp to Yes or something else in order to skip the tutorial
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"accountStatus"]) {
        [self initializeTutorial];
    } else {
        [self setupMainView];
    }


    self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    return YES;
}
```

**Here is my SignInViewController :**

```
#import "SignInViewController.h"

@interface SignInViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *password;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails*>* passwordAuthenticationCompletion;

@property (nonatomic,strong) AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse * response;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AWSCognitoIdentityUser * user;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool * pool;
@end

@implementation SignInViewController

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.password.text = nil;
    self.username.text = self.usernameText;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];
    NSLog(@"Pool:%@",self.pool);
    if(!self.user)
        NSLog(@"//SignInViewController:!self.user");
        self.user = [self.pool currentUser];
    [self refresh];
}
-(void) refresh {
    NSLog(@"//SignInViewController:refresh");

    [[self.user getDetails] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse *> * _Nonnull task) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.response = task.result;
            self.title = self.user.username;
            NSLog(@"//UserDetailTableViewController:reloadData");
            //[self.tableView reloadData];
        });
        return nil;
    }];
}

- (IBAction)signInPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"SignInPressed:%@",self.username.text);
    self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion.result = [[AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails alloc] initWithUsername:self.username.text password:self.password.text];
}


-(void) getPasswordAuthenticationDetails: (AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput *) authenticationInput  passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource: (AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails *> *) passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource {
    NSLog(@"getPasswordAuthenticationDetails:");

    self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion = passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource;
    NSLog(@"self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion:%@",passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(!self.usernameText)
            self.usernameText = authenticationInput.lastKnownUsername;
            NSLog(@"self.usernameText:%@",self.usernameText);
    });

}

-(void) didCompletePasswordAuthenticationStepWithError:(NSError*) error {
    NSLog(@"didCompletePasswordAuthenticationStepWithError:");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(error){
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:error.userInfo[@"__type"]
                                        message:error.userInfo[@"message"]
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Retry", nil] show];
        }else{
            self.usernameText = nil;
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    });
}

@end
```

**And here is the output in the log :**

```
2016-09-01 22:20:48.323 PS[84018:4547153] Pool:<AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool: 0x7fda09c2f0d0>
2016-09-01 22:20:48.324 PS[84018:4547153] AWS configuration:<AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration: 0x7fda09c3b2a0>
2016-09-01 22:20:48.324 PS[84018:4547153] AWS service configuration:<AWSServiceConfiguration: 0x7fda09c3b520>
2016-09-01 22:20:48.324 PS[84018:4547153] AWS Cognito Identity Pool:<AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration: 0x7fda09c3b2a0>
2016-09-01 22:20:48.324 PS[84018:4547153] Device Info:Name:iPhone Simulator Model:iPhone (iPhone OS:9.3)
2016-09-01 22:20:48.330 PS[84018:4547153] appDidBecomeActive
2016-09-01 22:20:50.315 PS[84018:4547153] Pool:<AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool: 0x7fda09c2f0d0>
2016-09-01 22:20:50.315 PS[84018:4547153] //SignInViewController:!self.user
2016-09-01 22:20:50.317 PS[84018:4547153] //SignInViewController:refresh
2016-09-01 22:20:50.317 PS[84018:4547153] startPasswordAuthentication
2016-09-01 22:20:50.318 PS[84018:4547153] //startPasswordAuthentication:self.signInViewController:<SignInViewController: 0x7fda09f1e920>
2016-09-01 22:20:50.319 PS[84018:4547153] getPasswordAuthenticationDetails:
2016-09-01 22:20:50.319 PS[84018:4547153] self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion:<AWSTaskCompletionSource: 0x7fda09c5b800>
2016-09-01 22:20:50.327 PS[84018:4547153] self.usernameText:(null)
2016-09-01 22:21:04.557 PS[84018:4547153] SignInPressed:testsamp
```

In the demo, once "signInPressed" is called, you see the log entry below, and more server responses.

```
2016-09-01 14:27:31.848 CognitoYourUserPoolsSample[77236:4278261] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.7 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:526 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersAndBodyForRequest:] | Request headers:
{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1";
    Host = "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
    "User-Agent" = "aws-sdk-iOS/2.4.7 iPhone-OS/9.3 en_US";
    "X-Amz-Date" = 20160901T182731Z;
    "X-Amz-Target" = "AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth";
}
```

I must be missing some little detail, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: Your code does look correct to me. You mentioned "more server responses", can you please update with those.

Also just confirming that you did not see any errors in the authentication, right? [No didCompletePasswordAuthenticationStepWithError in the logs]

Comment: The "more server responses" are just additional positive responses. But in my app, there are no responses other than the log entry I add.

Comment: This might be useful? My app uses most of the same code from their sample.  https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Objective-C

Comment: Thanks, but that's the sample I got my code from. The sample works fine using my AWS credentials and my user pool. But my app, using the sample code only works for sign up, but does not work when I try to log in.